# Displaying two graphs with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i'm trying to display charts while pulling data from JSON.

Here is my php file that encodes my json:

```
    <?php
header("content-type: application/json"); 

$chartData = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'country' => 'Utilities',
    'litres' => 501.8999999999999772626324556767940521240234375,
    'color' => '#1faf4b',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'country' => 'Insurance',
    'litres' => 301.8999999999999772626324556767940521240234375,
    'color' => '#79cf93',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'country' => 'Telcos',
    'litres' => 201.099999999999994315658113919198513031005859375,
    'color' => '#a5dfb7',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'country' => 'Entertainment',
    'litres' => 165.80000000000001136868377216160297393798828125,
    'color' => '#d2efdb',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'country' => 'Other',
    'litres' => 139.900000000000005684341886080801486968994140625,
    'color' => '#ffffff',
  ),
);

$chartDataRight = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'income' => 53.5,
    'expenses' => 18.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'value' => 60.3070000000000021600499167107045650482177734375,
    'year' => 2009,
    'date' => '20093rd MAR',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2009,
    'income' => 26.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875,
    'expenses' => 22.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125,
    'value' => 10.16799999999999926103555480949580669403076171875,
    'date' => '20093rd Apr',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2009,
    'income' => 30.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'expenses' => 23.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375,
    'value' => 20.07300000000000039790393202565610408782958984375,
    'date' => '20093rd May',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2009,
    'income' => 29.5,
    'expenses' => 25.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'value' => 30.0270000000000010231815394945442676544189453125,
    'date' => '20093rd June',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2009,
    'income' => 50.60000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'expenses' => 27.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875,
    'value' => 10.2509999999999994457766661071218550205230712890625,
    'dashLengthLine' => 5,
    'date' => '20093rd Jul',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2009,
    'income' => 34.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'expenses' => 29.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375,
    'dashLengthColumn' => 5,
    'alpha' => 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125,
    'value' => 50.28099999999999880628820392303168773651123046875,
    'additional' => '(projection)',
    'date' => '20093rd Aug',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2009,
    'income' => 53.5,
    'expenses' => 18.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'value' => 60.3070000000000021600499167107045650482177734375,
    'date' => '20093rd Sep',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2009,
    'income' => 26.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875,
    'expenses' => 22.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125,
    'value' => 10.16799999999999926103555480949580669403076171875,
    'date' => '20093rd Oct',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2009,
    'income' => 30.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'expenses' => 23.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375,
    'value' => 20.07300000000000039790393202565610408782958984375,
    'date' => '20093rd Nov',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2009,
    'income' => 29.5,
    'expenses' => 25.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'value' => 30.0270000000000010231815394945442676544189453125,
    'date' => '20093rd Dec',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'income' => 53.5,
    'expenses' => 18.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'value' => 60.3070000000000021600499167107045650482177734375,
    'year' => 2010,
    'date' => '20103rd MAR',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2010,
    'income' => 26.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875,
    'expenses' => 22.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125,
    'value' => 10.16799999999999926103555480949580669403076171875,
    'date' => '20103rd Apr',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2010,
    'income' => 30.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'expenses' => 23.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375,
    'value' => 20.07300000000000039790393202565610408782958984375,
    'date' => '20103rd May',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2010,
    'income' => 29.5,
    'expenses' => 25.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'value' => 30.0270000000000010231815394945442676544189453125,
    'date' => '20103rd June',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2010,
    'income' => 50.60000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'expenses' => 27.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875,
    'value' => 10.2509999999999994457766661071218550205230712890625,
    'date' => '20103rd Jul',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2010,
    'income' => 34.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'expenses' => 29.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375,
    'value' => 50.28099999999999880628820392303168773651123046875,
    'date' => '20103rd Aug',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  16 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2010,
    'income' => 53.5,
    'expenses' => 18.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'value' => 60.3070000000000021600499167107045650482177734375,
    'date' => '20103rd Sep',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  17 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2010,
    'income' => 26.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875,
    'expenses' => 22.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125,
    'value' => 10.16799999999999926103555480949580669403076171875,
    'date' => '20103rd Oct',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  18 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2010,
    'income' => 30.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'expenses' => 23.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375,
    'value' => 20.07300000000000039790393202565610408782958984375,
    'date' => '20103rd Nov',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#178539',
      1 => '#1faf4b',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'white',
  ),
  19 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2017,
    'income' => 29.5,
    'expenses' => 25.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'value' => 30.0270000000000010231815394945442676544189453125,
    'date' => '20173rd Dec',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#FFFFFF',
      1 => '#cccccc',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'black',
  ),
  20 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2017,
    'income' => 53.5,
    'expenses' => 18.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'value' => 60.3070000000000021600499167107045650482177734375,
    'date' => '20117rd MAR',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#FFFFFF',
      1 => '#cccccc',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'black',
  ),
  21 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2017,
    'income' => 26.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875,
    'expenses' => 22.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125,
    'value' => 10.16799999999999926103555480949580669403076171875,
    'date' => '20117rd Apr',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#FFFFFF',
      1 => '#cccccc',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'black',
  ),
  22 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2017,
    'income' => 30.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'expenses' => 23.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375,
    'value' => 20.07300000000000039790393202565610408782958984375,
    'date' => '20117rd May',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#FFFFFF',
      1 => '#cccccc',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'black',
  ),
  23 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2017,
    'income' => 29.5,
    'expenses' => 25.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'value' => 30.0270000000000010231815394945442676544189453125,
    'date' => '20173rd June',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#FFFFFF',
      1 => '#cccccc',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'black',
  ),
  24 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2017,
    'income' => 50.60000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'expenses' => 27.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875,
    'value' => 10.2509999999999994457766661071218550205230712890625,
    'dashLengthLine' => 5,
    'date' => '20173rd Jul',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#FFFFFF',
      1 => '#cccccc',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'black',
  ),
  25 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2017,
    'income' => 34.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'expenses' => 29.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375,
    'dashLengthColumn' => 5,
    'alpha' => 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125,
    'value' => 50.28099999999999880628820392303168773651123046875,
    'date' => '20173rd Aug',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#FFFFFF',
      1 => '#cccccc',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'black',
  ),
  26 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2017,
    'income' => 53.5,
    'expenses' => 18.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'value' => 60.3070000000000021600499167107045650482177734375,
    'date' => '20173rd Sep',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#FFFFFF',
      1 => '#cccccc',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'black',
  ),
  27 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2017,
    'income' => 26.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875,
    'expenses' => 22.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125,
    'value' => 10.16799999999999926103555480949580669403076171875,
    'date' => '20173rd Oct',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#FFFFFF',
      1 => '#cccccc',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'black',
  ),
  28 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2017,
    'income' => 30.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'expenses' => 23.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375,
    'value' => 20.07300000000000039790393202565610408782958984375,
    'date' => '20173rd Nov',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#FFFFFF',
      1 => '#cccccc',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'black',
  ),
  29 => 
  array (
    'year' => 2017,
    'income' => 29.5,
    'expenses' => 25.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625,
    'value' => 30.0270000000000010231815394945442676544189453125,
    'date' => '20173rd Dec',
    'color' => 
    array (
      0 => '#FFFFFF',
      1 => '#cccccc',
    ),
    'strColor' => 'black',
  ),
);
    //echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($chartDataRight) . ')';

    echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($chartDataRight) . ')' . '('. json_encode($chartData) . ')';  

?>
```

Here is my json outpout:

https://www.loly.com.au/ebp/jsonp.php?callback=?

Then in javascript I do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://www.loly.com.au/ebp/jsonp.php?callback=?', function(chartDataRight, chartData) {
  // assign ChartDataRight to chart1, assign ChartData to chart2
}
```

However, I can only display 1 chart, depending on what data I pass first.

Any Idea how I can display both charts?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: use a each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a each loop

change you php to return a array:

```
echo $_GET['callback']. '(['. json_encode($chartDataRight).','. json_encode($chartData) . '])';
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://www.loly.com.au/ebp/jsonp.php?callback=?', function(chartData) {
 $.each(chartData,function(){
  //initi each chart
 })
}
```